# choice_attr in EntityType in Symfony 4.4 not work

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a form with a list of checkboxes and I would like to display the archived services with the "text-muted" class (which displays the text more clearly).
With the code below, there is no error but the class is not applied.

```
$builder->add('prestationTypes', EntityType::class, [
  'class'         => 'App\Entity\PrestationType',
  'choice_label' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
     return $value->getLibelle() . ' ' . ($value->getIsArchived() ? '(archivée)' : '');
  },
  'multiple'      => true,
  'expanded'      => true,
  'required'      => false,
  'by_reference'  => false,
  'placeholder'   => 'Choisissez...',
  'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($autoecole) {
    return $er->getPTByCategorie($autoecole, 'planning');
   },
  'choice_attr' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
    return $value->getIsArchived() ? ['class' => 'text-muted'] : ['class' => ''];
  },
]);
```

It's displayed like this in my view.

```
<div class="form-group">
   {{ form_label(form.prestationTypes, 'Types de tickets rattachés') }}
   {{ form_widget(form.prestationTypes) }}
</div>
```

And the current result (without the archived lines in more clear).

[liste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y3cA.png)

Comment: Have you tried it with the [label_attr](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#label-attr) instead?

Comment: label_attr modifies the general label ('Types de tickets rattachés' in my case). Also, I can't pass it a function because the following error is returned: ''The option "label_attr" with value Closure is expected to be of type "array", but is of type "Closure".".

Comment: Without the function, the variable $value is unknown.

Comment: I tried like this :
` 'choice_attr' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
                    return $value->getIsArchived() ? [$key => ['class' => 'text-muted']] : [$key => ['class' => '']];
                }, `
Replacing $key by $index, $value->getId() or $value->getLibelle() but it gives me the error An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice : Array to string conversion").